# How to place an ellipsis in the center of the content of a label or a text of a textbloxk

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, .net-4.5

if i'm using following code

`<Stackpanel>
    <TextBlock TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">abcdefghijklmn1234567890</TextBlock>
</Stackpanel>`

i get following result:

```
abcdefghijklmn1234...
```

My question is if it is possible to archive following behaviour:

```
abcdefghij...234567890
```

Has anyone an idea how this can work?

Comment: Without using a Converter and ugly calculations, the only way I can think of is using two different TextBlocks/Labels... But in that case, the second part of the text is always gonna be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be ugly, but you could find the length of the textblock text then divide this by 2 to find out where the middle of the string is. Then you can take the value of that substring and do a replace of itself with the ellipses added. You'll have to decide how to deal with content that does not have an even number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

With XAML only

```
<Grid ToolTip="My tooltip">
    <TextBlock Margin="0,0,60,0" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Text="This is very long line that ended with 123">
    </TextBlock>
    <Grid Width="60" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" TextAlignment="Left" Text="This is very long line that ended with 123"></TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```